# No clock signal at the SCL pin of Sparkfun nRF52832 breakout board

Tags: i2c, nrf52

I am trying to use the Sparkfun nRF52832 breakout board as a master in I2C communication. I am using Arduino IDE to program the module. I defined pins 24 and 25 as SCL and SDA, respectively, and used wire.begin() in the setup to configure it as a master. I expect to see the clock signal when I connect the board to the oscilloscope, but I just see 3.3v dc signals at both scl and sda pins. Would you please tell me what's wrong?

I used pull-up resistors.

Comment: To clarify: Do you expect to see clock signal when I2C is enabled or actually communicating with something. It should only be in the latter case.

Comment: now I can see the clock signal, but it interferes with the connected device. I don't have any control over the device, which is configured as a master. It pulls down the clock of nRF52 module.

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is and what you are asking.